# Dynamically loading a style sheet on different domain doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to dynamically load css and js using javascript that's referencing another domain. On IE and Chrome everything works as expected, however it does not work in Firefox and I get the following error:

```
InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object
```

I've seen many posts about this searching around, but I can't find any solutions that will actually fix this issue. Here is the code that I'm using.

```
    // Helper method to add js or css files
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    var fileref;
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        fileref=document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        fileref=document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
    }
    if (typeof fileref!=="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}

function goMobile() {
// Load bootstrap and jquery 11
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.onload = function () {
    var bootstrap = document.createElement( 'script' );
    bootstrap.onload = function() {
        $jq11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

        loadjscssfile("https://example.com/inject/bootstrap-overrides.css", "css");

    };
    bootstrap.src = 'https://example.com/applications/bootstrap.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(bootstrap);   
};
script.src = 'https://example.com/inject/jquery-1.11.2.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle also:

https://jsfiddle.net/0py613h6/1/

Comment: Please add jQuery to your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really care for this solution, but what I did was read the css in using ajax and append it directly as a style to the page. I would still be interested in how, or if I can dynamically load a css from another domain using the link tag. Here's an example of my loadCSS method.

```
function loadCSS(url){

    $jq11.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
            var css = result,
            head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            style = document.createElement('style');

            style.type = 'text/css';
            if (style.styleSheet){
                style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
            } else {
                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
            }

            head.appendChild(style);

        }
    });
}
```